# Get JQuery position relative to whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on hacking a [PDF reader](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) to make some changes, and I want to use JQuery to get positions of some elements such as links. I use

> jQuery(this).position()

Apparently this gives me the position relative to a page in the PDF, not the entire document! So if the element appears at the top of page 9, the "top" position gives a very small value, even though it is down in page 9. Is there a way to get the position relative to the whole document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure about this, but try $(this).offset()

Comment: I think it's not quite what I want in my question, but it turns out it helps me achieve my end goal anyway. Thanks!